# Mount a VHD (VirtualBox) in OSX

Tags: macos, virtualbox, mount, osx-mountain-lion, vhd

How can I mount a VHD (created in VirtualBox) of a Ubuntu Server install on my Max OSX (Mountain Lion) and allow it to be found in Finder (so I can select a folder and view it's contents).

If it requires me to purchase something, I am fine with that. Otherwise free is preferred.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the MacFUSE version from here: http://www.matthewratzloff.com/blog/2012/03/12/macfusion-on-os-x-lion/

Then, install the newest MacFusion App from here: http://macfusionapp.org/

This utilizes the existing SFTP abilities and achieves the same goal. Only way I found, and I've been looking for days!

Answer (score 6):

There is an app for that: Paragon Virtual Disk Mounter.
Beta version is available here:
http://www.paragon-software.com/support/betatesting/vd-mounter-mac-beta/index.html

.vhd, .vmdk, .vdi are supported at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, to mount a vhd (virtualbox or other), it is safer to be of fixed size, using "/usr/bin/hdiutil" according to

**`"/usr/bin/hdiutil attach -imagekey diskimage-class=CRawDiskImage /path_to_your_vhd"`**

Answer (score 0):

This answer on ServerFault gives details on how to mount a VHD file created by Windows Backup (from Windows 7 or Windows 8) on a Mac. https://serverfault.com/questions/174278/mount-an-vhd-on-mac-os-x/1000645#1000645

It's not very straightforward, but, I did get it working!